# como exportar rdlc a word?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, reportviewer, c#-8.0, report

me gustaria poder exportar de este reporteador a word, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo, si me puede facilitar una linea de codigo se lo agradecere.

```
ReportParameter[] reportParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
reportParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("ReportParameter1", 
      ClaseDatos.fechaoficio, false);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

he buscando en internet pero no entiendo como adaptarlo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184042/how-do-i-export-directly-to-a-word-document-in-report-viewer